# Rename the Middle Name/Initial to Father's Name

Tags: magento-1.9, registration, name

I need to rename the field of Middle Name/Initial in my registration form: https://www.khouryhome.com/customer/account/create/ to Father's name and want to make it mandatory and not optional like it is now in the system-->customer configuration.
Thanks in advance for the help.

```
<div class="field name-middlename">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>" class="required"><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename'); ?> FATHER NAME <em>*</em></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('middlename')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getMiddlename()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('middlename') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

this is for the first name:

```
<div class="field name-firstname">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname')?>" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('firstname')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?>" maxlength="255" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the following file:

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/widget/name.phtml

to your theme like below:

> app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/customer/widget/name.phtml

And change the text.

For make it required from database:

Goto **eav_attribute** table and find the **middlename** attribute code and change the field **is_required** to 1.

Also from here you can change the Text of **Middle name** to **Father's name** as well.

Change the following in **name.phtml**:

```
<div class="field name-middlename">
    <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>" class="required">FATHER NAME <em>*</em></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('middlename')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getMiddlename()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?>" class="input-text required-entry<?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('middlename') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: dear for the required its well received, as for the renaming im still lost in this label where i should change the name? <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>"<?php echo $isMiddlenameRequired ? ' class="required"' : '' ?>><?php echo $isMiddlenameRequired ? '<em>*</em>' : '' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?></label>

Comment: as for Goto eav_attribute table and find the middlename attribute code and change the field is_required to 1.--> i dont have attributes with first name, middle name or last name. if its at level database, where exactly are you pointing? you mean SQL or PHP MY ADMIN? up their i should change it??

Comment: You can find the label in the same table. I mean magento database from phpmyadmin.

Comment: dear i prefer not to change anything from the database of SQL or PHP MY ADMIN, cant we just rename it in the registration file in this line of code:  <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>"<?php echo $isMiddlenameRequired ? ' class="required"' : '' ?>><?php echo $isMiddlenameRequired ? '<em>*</em>' : '' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?></label>

Comment: Yes you can change it from there but  if somewhere the same thing happens then you need to change that manually. Database change will effect for every places.

Comment: dear its not working i tried several times the rename

Comment: <div class="field name-firstname">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname')?>" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('firstname')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?>" maxlength="255" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('fi

Comment: That means any module override this file? Can you check it by enabling template path hints for correct location? Also flush the cache if its enabled.

Comment: for the first name its working, last name as well but middle name i could insert this name: MIDDLE NAME/INITIAL father's name but its not mandatory, the class required is not working!!! please advice

Comment: i have this line before the middle name, shall i remove it? <?php if ($this->showMiddlename()): ?>
<?php $isMiddlenameRequired = $this->isMiddlenameRequired(); ?>

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: dear i checked it. the name of the label is working just great now, the input box is not required, i mean if you want you can insert first name, last name and without the father's name. the mandatory field is not working!!

Comment: For required you need to edit the database table or you can put required-entry class to your input field.

Comment: From the admin panel in Magento, in customer configuration , i have Always optional for the Show Middle Name (initial), is it fine to add the required-entry class to your input field???

Comment: yes. it only put validation for client side.

Comment: <div class="input-box required-entry">
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('middlename')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getMiddlename()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('middlename') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
        </div>
    </div> but its still not required!! the input box is not highlighting required like first and last name!!

Comment: <div class="field name-middlename">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>" class="required">FATHER NAME <em>*</em><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename'); ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('middlename')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getMiddlename()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('midd

Comment: Can you add this in your question as its not showing full content.

Comment: necessary done now please double check from your side the question. clear?

Comment: So according to your its not working. I have done small modification to your code and updated it to my answer.

Comment: wouwwwwwwwwwwwww your the king, you are the man!!! its working now love it!! its amazing ; appreciate your great support yesterday and today finally some actions! :)

Comment: Welcome. Happy coding :)